# How can I create the following design in react native using SVG?

Tags: react-native, svg

Does anyone know how can I create the following design using SVG? I have the path image in SVG format, so using that in [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/playground/?native=true), I created the path, now I need to add the circles in random order over the path. any leads will be appreciated.

[image]

Edit:
SVG code for path

```
    <Svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width={395.215}
      height={180.855}
      viewBox="0 0 395.215 180.855"
      {...props}>

      <Path
        fill="none"
        stroke="#ecece9"
        strokeWidth={15}
        d="M7.146 160.744c16.087-50.465 64.229-94.319 115.671-92.656s60.239 86.363 89.6 100.623 47.453-4.982 51.241-65.74 24.858-126.75 61.62-79.227 62.437 90.632 62.437 115.574"
      />
    </Svg>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are there only `seven` points?

Comment: I would try to put those points at some specific coordinates along the path (they might be images I guess). There is some example here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg#image if it helps. I mean those points would be separate from your path ( `<Path ... /> <Image  {...coordinates here} /> <Image {...other coordinates here} />`)

Comment: @KartikeyVaish It will change according to data from the API.

Comment: @dianaqqq Thanks, I will check this

Comment: It does not look like a _random order_. I suppose you need to distribute N points evenly along the length of your path. Is it correct?

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky you are correct, the random order I mentioned was about the number of circles that will be there in a path, in the image shared, there are only 7 circles, that might change to 10 or 5, I'm not sure how I can distribute this evenly.

Answer (score 3):

No need for any script (other than **creating** the SVG)

- create `<circle>` elements with an `<animateMotion>` inside
- and a Motion Path reference to the single path: `<mpath href="#PATH"></mpath>`
- `keyTimes` defines the path 'length' from **0** to **1**
- `keyPoints` positions the circles with float values between **0** and **1**
- set the `dur`ation to `0.001s` for instant display

[image]

```html
<style>
  svg{
    height:180px;
    background:pink;
  }
</style>
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 200">
  <style>
   circle{ r:15 }
   [done]{ fill:green }
   [todo]{ fill:yellow }
  </style>
  <path id="PATH" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="15" d="M7 161c16-50 64-94 116-93s60 86 90 101s47-5 51-66s25-127 62-79s62 91 62 116"></path>
  <circle done>
    <animateMotion dur="1s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;.1" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear"><mpath href="#PATH"></mpath></animateMotion>
  </circle>
  <circle done>
    <animateMotion dur="1s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;.2" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear"><mpath href="#PATH"></mpath></animateMotion>
  </circle>
  <circle done>
    <animateMotion dur="1s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;.3" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear"><mpath href="#PATH"></mpath></animateMotion>
  </circle>
  <g><circle todo></circle>
     <text text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle">04</text>
      <animateMotion dur="1s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;.4" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear"><mpath href="#PATH"></mpath></animateMotion>
  </g>
  <g><circle todo></circle>
     <text text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle">05</text>
      <animateMotion dur="0.01s" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;.5" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear"><mpath href="#PATH"></mpath></animateMotion>
  </g>
</svg>
```

#### Update: I dabbled a bit with a Native! Web Component:

```html
<svg-spread-on-path duration="1" path="P">
  <style>
    svg    { width: 100%; height:180px; background: pink }
    circle { r: 15}
    [done] { fill: green }
    [todo] { fill: yellow }
  </style>
  <path id="P" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="15" d="M7 161c16-50 64-94 116-93s60 86 90 101s47-5 51-66s25-127 62-79s62 91 62 116"></path>
  <circle done />
  <circle done />
  <circle done />
  <circle done />
  <circle todo />
  <circle todo />
  <circle todo />
</svg-spread-on-path>
<script>
  customElements.define("svg-spread-on-path", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      let svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
      svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 400 200");
      super().attachShadow({mode: "open"}).append(this.svg = svg);
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.svg.innerHTML = this.innerHTML; //   svg.append(...this.children);
        let circles = [...this.svg.querySelectorAll("circle")];
        this.svg.append(...circles.map((circle, idx) => {
          let path = this.getAttribute("path");
          let duration = this.getAttribute("duration") || 1 / 100;
          let state = circle.hasAttribute("done") ? "done" : "todo";
          let label = idx;
          let keypoint = idx * 1 / (circles.length - 1);
          let group = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
          group.innerHTML = `<circle ${state}></circle>` +
            `<text text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle">${label}</text>` +
            `<animateMotion dur="${duration}" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" keyPoints="0;${keypoint}" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear"><mpath href="#${path}"></mpath></animateMotion>`;
          circle.remove();
          group.onclick = evt => group.querySelector("animateMotion").beginElement();
          return group;
        }));
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out. while quickly checking out the same on the application, I found that some things are missing, I'm assuming this is for React and not React Native. please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm looking for React Native solutions. however, I will try to find the equivalent part for react native

Comment: Excellent solution, love it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the positions of points using this simple routine:

```
const getPointsAlongPath = (path, number) => {
 const length = path.getTotalLength();
 return (new Array(number)).fill(0).map((_, i) => path.getPointAtLength(length / (number - 1) * i))
};
```

, where `path` is a Path element and `number` is number of points you want to place along the path.

React code may be something like this:

```
const PathWithPoints({path, number}) => {
  const pathRef = useRef();
  const points = getPointsAlongPath(pathRef.current, number);

  return (
    <svg>
      <path d={path} ref={pathRef} ... />
      {points.map(({x, y}) => (<circle cx={x} cy={y} r={...} fill={...} />)}
    </svg>
  )
}
```

```js
const getPointsAlongPath = (path, number) => {
 const length = path.getTotalLength();
 return (new Array(number)).fill(0).map((_, i) => path.getPointAtLength(length / (number - 1) * i))
};

const svg = d3.select('svg');
const path = svg.select('path');
const points = getPointsAlongPath(path.node(), 8);
points.forEach(({x, y}) => svg.append('circle').attr('cx', x).attr('cy', y)
.attr('r', 15).style('fill', 'red'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg
      width="450"
      height="180"
      viewBox="0 0 395.215 180.855"
>
<path
        fill="none"
        stroke="#ecece9"
        stroke-width="15"
        d="M15 160.744c16.087-50.465 64.229-94.319 115.671-92.656s60.239 86.363 89.6 100.623 47.453-4.982 51.241-65.74 24.858-126.75 61.62-79.227 62.437 90.632 62.437 115.574"
      />
 </Svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out. I had seen similar code parts in [William Candillon youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i20R4lwkJzw&t=62s) video, He has his own package called `react native redash` to parse the path and calculate the position. 
I will take both code as reference and try to make the component in React Native.